# How to drop mysql row using bind_param with now()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

How to drop mysql row using bind_param with now() ?

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$stmt = $db_mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM transfer_check WHERE delete_date_time < ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", now());
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

I tried to use this my code but not work (it's not drop any row) how can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

I understand `NOW()` is SQL, and you want to use php so you should be able to use:

`$stmt->bind_param("s", (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to:

```
$stmt = $db_mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM transfer_check WHERE delete_date_time < NOW()");
```

then you won't need a `bind_param` at all.